# LIKE clause INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with 2 tables:

table A

```
IDA | Description
1   | BIG_MAN
2   | BIG_MANCA
3   | WEB_BrowserCOM
4   | WEB_BrowserCO
5   | Other
```

Table B

```
IDB | FileName
1   | BIG_MAN_98267828_29292
2   | BIG_MANCA_8282836662_92992
3   | WEB_BrowserCO_7263562_82828
4   | WEB_Browser_28828288_826662
5   | WEB_BrowserCOM_9374664_9933
```

What I would like to do is get the IDA doing a inner join with table B:

```
;WITH FileDetails AS
    (
    SELECT 
        FL.IDA,
        FL.Description
    FROM TableA FL
    WHERE IsActive = 1 
)
SELECT 
    FD.IDA,
    FLL.FileName
    FD.Description
FROM TableB FLL
    INNER JOIN TableA FD
ON FLL.FileName LIKE (FD.Filename)+'%'
```

However I get:

```
IDA | FileName                        |Description
1   | BIG_MAN_98267828_29292          |BIG_MAN
1   | BIG_MANCA_8282836662_92992      |BIG_MAN
4   | WEB_BrowserCO_7263562_82828     |WEB_BrowserCO
4   | WEB_Browser_28828288_826662     |WEB_BrowserCO
4   | WEB_BrowserCOM_9374664_9933     |WEB_BrowserCO
```

Any idea to solve this and get the correct IDA?

Comment: Your query seems to work.  What results do you want?

Comment: What can you rely on in this structure? Are rows in TableB always suffixed by 2 numbers separated by undescores after the part that should be an excat match to a row from A?

Comment: Stop! WEB_BrowserCO is a subset of WEB_BrowserCOM. Anything that matches the second will also match the first. Your path seems suspicious. And WEB_BrowserCo does not match WEB_BROWSER_anything - so your expected output is not reasonable.

Comment: Yes!, they are  always suffixed by 2 numbers separated by undescores after the Description

Comment: I think the best solution is take the string before second underscore, I mean find the second underscore and compare

Comment: Do any of your Table A entries ever end in an underscore?

Comment: David, 852_AMAZON_   and 852_AMAZONCA_ in table A

Comment: table A: BIG_MAN,BIG_MANCA,WEB_BrowserCOM,WEB_BrowserCO,Other,852_AMAZON_,852_AMAZONCA_,SYX001_ AND STF01_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that you're not including a trailing underscore in your like clause.  Try this:

```
WITH FileDetails AS
    (
    SELECT 
        FL.IDA,
        FL.Description
    FROM TableA FL
    WHERE IsActive = 1 
)
SELECT 
    FD.IDA,
    FLL.FileName
    FD.Description
FROM TableB FLL
    INNER JOIN TableA FD
ON FLL.FileName LIKE (FD.Filename)+'$_%' escape '$'
```

Comment: it worked for almost all my record but these






Table A

ID | Description
7  |  852_AMAZON_
8  |852_AMAZONCA_

7 | 852_AMAZON_9494282516_74715706439014_01022 | 852_AMAZON_
7 | 852_AMAZONCA_9494282516_741097948349 | 852_AMAZON_

Comment: Pablo, can you clarify the data you just put in this comment?  Are these the results of a query, or are these the Table A entries that aren't working, and the Table B entries they're matching up to?

Comment: hey the issue was because another table but your solution worked!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you just need a better `like` pattern:

```
SELECT FD.IDA, FLL.FileName, FD.Description
FROM TableB FLL INNER JOIN
     TableA FD
     ON FLL.FileName LIKE FD.Filename + '%$_%' ESCAPE '$';
```

This looks for the name followed by an underscore.  The `ESCAPE` is needed because `'_'` is a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data you may find the answers already provided are sufficient, but I wasn't keen on them ...

They make two assumptions which may not hold:

1. The underscores within your "descriptions" will not create a match with other data by being interpreted as a wildcard.

Add to `TableB` a filename of `'BIGAMAN_123456_123456'` to illustrate the issue.

2. When one description matches another except for a "tail" that tail doesn't begin with an underscore.

Add to `TableA` a description of `'BIG_MAN_7'` to illustrate the issue.

If SQL-Server had good native handling of RegEx objects, I'd make a suggestion along those lines, but since it doesn't:...

```
SELECT 
    FD.IDA,
    FLL.FileName,
    FD.Description
FROM TableB FLL
    INNER JOIN @TableA FD ON

left(FLL.FileName,len(fd.description)+1) = fd.description + '_' AND
   len(replace(fll.FileName,fd.description + '_','')) - 
   len(replace(replace(fll.FileName,fd.description + '_',''),'_','')) = 1
```

The first part of the join does the same job as the `like` versions but avoids treating any subtrings as wildcards. The second part takes the remainder of the filename, and checks that it contains only one underscore.